# modeling of random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have 2 random variables $U$, $V$ - uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. How to model (simulate) random variable with distribution function 
$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}e^\frac{-x}{2} \mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty)}(x)$

Comment: Use generalized inverse function.

Comment: I changed the question to reflect what I think is a more standard notation, can you confirm that's what you had in mind? I am not sure because the PDF is then not correct (the integral is not $1$). However, with the PDF $f(x)=\frac12 e^{x/2}$, we get an exponential distribution (and the integral is $1$ over $[0,+\infty[$), and then it's trivial to get a random sample by the inverse method, using a single uniform random sample: write that the CDF is equal to a uniform random variate $U$, this leads to $X=-2\log(1-U)$, or equivalently $X=-2\log U$.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The indicator is from 0 to +infinity

Comment: Ok, then the last part of my comment applies, as this is an [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Generating_exponential_variates).